# Button function calling another function

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick, getelementbyid

im just a beginner and i want to find the answer to this problem.

This is my html code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type = "text" name = "step" id = "step">
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
        <p id = "demo"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my javascript code.

```
var step = document.getElementById("step").innerHTML;
parseInt(step);

function matchHouses(step) {
    var num = 0;
    var one = 1;
    while (num != step){
        one += 5;
        num++;
    }
    return one;
}
function myFunction(){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = matchHouses(step);
}
```

What I did is to call the function matchHouses(step) by the click of the button. But the output is always 1. I also put parseInt to the step id as it is string but it is still doesnt work. I was expecting an output of 1+5 if the input is 1, 1+5+5 if the input is two and so on. How do I make it work?

Comment: Are you expecting a string that looks like `1+5` or are you expecting `1+5` to be evaluated to `6`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two key things are that a) `parseInt` won't do the evaluation "in place". It either needs to be assigned to a variable, or the evaluation done as you're passing it into the `matchHouse` function, and b) you should be getting the `value` of the input element, not the `innerHTML`.

Here are some additional notes:

1. Cache all the elements first.
2. Add an event listener in your JavaScript rather than using inline JS in the HTML.
3. No need to have an additional variable for counting - just decrement `step` until it reaches zero.
4. [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) may be a more suitable alternative to `parseInt` which requires a radix to work properly. [It doesn't always default to base 10 if you leave it out](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#parameters).
5. Assign the result of calling the function to `demo`'s `textContent` (not `innerHTML` as it is just a simple string, and not a string of HTML markup.

```js
// Cache elements
const step = document.querySelector('#step');
const demo = document.querySelector('#demo');
const button = document.querySelector('button');

// Add a listener to the button
button.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

function matchHouses(step) {
  let out = 1;
  while (step > 0) {
    out += 5;
    --step;
  }
  return out;
}

function handleClick() {

  // Get the value of the input string and
  // coerce it to a number
  const n = Number(step.value);
  demo.textContent = matchHouses(n);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="text" name="step" id="step">
  <button type="button">Submit</button>
  <p id="demo"></p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote your code like this:

```js
let step = 0;
    function handleInput(e){
      step = e.value;
    }
function matchHouses(step) {
    var num = 0;
    var one = 1;
    while (num != step){
        one += 5;
        num++;
    }
    return one;
}
function myFunction(){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = matchHouses(step);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type = "text" name="step" id="step" onkeyup='handleInput(this)'>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
        <p id = "demo"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).